# Git commit with broken date

Tags: git, commit, git-amend

I've got an issue with a commit in a Git repo (It's big, and old), the commit in question was apparently committed on 1 Jan 2138, which is clearly wrong. As far as I know it should be 1st Oct 2019. The commit is on remote and there is a-lot commits after it (Probs like 1000 odd).

I've tried to rebase and amend the commit date but I think it's so far back in the history nothing seems to want to work.

```
git rebase -i <hash>
```

Took me about 30mins to find it in the rebase but changed pick to edit, but it just breaks on a conflict even though I have no changes.

I found this because I need to run git-filter-repo but it crashes as soon as it reaches the commit as the raw date is invalid.

```
fatal: Invalid raw date "5301595117 -27961850" in ident: DEvan <me@email.com> 5301595117 -27961850
```

If anyone knows a way to either change the date of the commit or just remove it entirely (Doesn't contain much), that'd be grand.

Comment: The basic problem with this is that because the date line is actually invalid, everything that works by copying commits gives up when it hits the invalid date line. Filter-branch and filter-repo work by copying commits. So does rebasing, for that matter. You'll need some tool that doesn't just give up at this point.

Comment: Without trying it, I don't know if using `git replace` to make a graft that skips over the bad commit will work, but that's worth a try: put in a graft that skips over the commit and see if filter-repo uses the grafted commit. Or, if you want to keep (but fix ie replace with improved one) the commit that's bad, use `git replace` to make a human-edited copy (see the `--edit` option) with a corrected date.

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me:

```
git replace
```